# Getting Transaction Amount on the Transaction History

Tags: transactions

When I query for the transaction history of a solana wallet using the **getSignaturesForAddress** method, I don't get to see the amount that was transacted for each transaction. Is there a way I can view the transacted amount for each transaction that is returned on the transaction history array?

Answer (score 1):

yes, in the parsed transaction object you have pre and post balances for each token involved in the transaction & pre and post balances for sol.

In the array of balances, the accounts are in the same order than in the transaction in many cases.

Comment: I don't think the getSignaturesForAddress method returns preBalances and postBalances for transactions.

Comment: There's one step missing, which is that you need to call `getTransaction` for each signature returned to get the full information https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction